Awarding a bounty on closed question
Here is my story:

I created a question.
I added a bounty on it.
The question was closed (I closed it as a duplicate).

Now I'm in limbo. It is closed, it doesn't have any answers, but Stack Overflow tells me to award the bounty in 24 hours.
What should I do? What happens next?
EDIT
Related feature request here.

If you can, edit the question so that it's on-topic; as a bountied question, then it'll get more attention and may get opened quicker. If you can't, you have lost your bountied reputation.

Next, the bounty will end.

You don't need to do anything, the bounty will simply expire (which is also what would have happened if your question was open but had no answers)

@ThomA I don't want to reopen question. It is correctly closed as duplicate.

Being able to vote to close bountied questions is a recent change. Previously putting a bounty on a question made said question immune to closure for the duration of the bounty, which caused some frustrations, as questions that were clearly off-topic (and had been missed initially by curators, we are human after all), were getting bountied and therefore nothing could be done about them apart from moderator flagging.
When you bounty a question, you are "promoting" it to the community and therefore the question will likely get more views. As such if you bounty a question that is off-topic, or a duplicate, you should expect that question to be closed. In the event it is closed, your actions should be the same: edit said question to meet the requirements of the site or why the duplicate post did not answer your question.
If you can't improve the question, because it is off-topic, your bounty is lost; learn from the mistake and don't bounty off-topic questions. You don't need to do anything.
If the linked question did answer your problem, great! Your bounty got you the answer you wanted, and served its purpose. Unfortunately you can't give your bounty to an answer on the linked duplicate, so the reputation is also "lost" and therefore you don't need to do anything. I'm sure, however, the community would be more than happy to vote on a  feature-request* asking for the ability to give a bounty to an answer on a linked duplicate, should a question be closed as a duplicate during the bounty period.
*There is now a post for this: If a bountied question is closed as a duplicate, allow the bounty to be awarded to an answer on the duplicate

Feature request is great idea, but I'm not sure I have energy to advocate for it and just create it and forget doesn't look responsible for me.

If i don't see such a request materialise by the end of the week, I might create one myself in truth, @talex .

Honestly, sounds like a really great idea though I don't know how it would be to implement. You're spot-on that a bounty paid for the exposure and ultimately found the answer (which likely would not have happened without the bounty) but it'd be nice to also reward the existing answer for something that was helpful.

Obligatory "also, people who find the dupe should get some rep, the incentive system is broken otherwise."

I've gone ahead and posted a [[meta-tag:feature-request]] for awarding the bounty to a dupe target's answer.

@HenryEcker or even awarding the bounty to users who identified the duplicate

@HenryEcker: Feels easy to implement in SQL server. One update statement to move the bounty to the question it belongs on. Logically speaking it can be done in a few hours assuming remotely sane code.

I'd suggest you're over simplifying things even in the "sane code" scenario @Joshua You have the bounty entry, plus the revision history entries, plus the reputation history entries at a minimum and that's if you're OK with there being no history of the bounty transfer. You also need to trigger a re-render of the HTML for the page. And that's just if you consider every closure to be automatically valid, which is probably not the standard.

What happens when a gold tag badge holder adds multiple duplicate targets? Which question do you transfer the bounty to? Should you give the asker the option to choose? Do you automatically transfer the bounty on closure? Or just if the question is closed when the bounty ends? What if the question is closed as a duplicate a minute before the bounty ended? And what if the asker disagrees with the duplicate target? Do you transfer the bounty to the duplicate target regardless? Or do you only transfer after the Asker confirms they agree it's a duplicate?

There's also the case where the bountied question receives an answer first then is later closed as a duplicate. Do you still transfer the bounty to the duplicate target? What if the asker finds the answer to their question to be better than the answers on the duplicate target (even if they agree it's a duplicate)? Should they have the option to award the bounty to answers of their question first?

IMHO the best option would be to have an award UI that displayed all answers from their own question, plus any answers on the linked duplicates, and allow them to select the post they found most helpful. Leaving the bounty events on the original question and only add the award entry to the answer. But that would involve building an entirely new UI even if it simplifies the backend since you'd only need to change the award target answer ID on submit.

That sounds like a comment for the [[meta-tag:feature-request]], @HenryEcker . :)

@HenryEcker: Actually I was thinking of bounty poster gets a button to transfer bounty to duplicate question; and was OK with rewriting the history to make it always on the duplicate.
